# testing a boost example

Tags: boost, compilation, boost-filesystem

This is my first test using Boost (1.5.3). I made an example with FileSystem class.

I think I've installed successfully the binary distribution, i.e., run bootstrap.bat and b2.exe to create headers & libraries in the installed folder.

if I'm correct, there is no dll lib, just static libraries & header files which I've pointed to in VS2008 project configuration.

I go compile and got this:

```
Error   1   fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.obj'    test_filesystem test_filesystem
```

what type of error is this? I think the compiler already sees the required files & libs

Thanks

Edit 01:

I originally added the wrong lib name (lack of ".lib"), I've correted it but now it gets 
 "Error 15  fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib' test_filesystem test_filesystem"

Do I put the library name correctly? -> libboost_filesystem-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib? I normally put library name like this, and I'm sure I've added the right path to this static lib

Comment: "I think the compiler already sees" -> have you verified that?

Comment: I right-click in the code, open the header and it shows. And there is no external linking error here which mostly shows when no static lib is found

Comment: The error you got is an error shown when no static lib is found. I don't get you.

Comment: I normally see "unresolved external symbol... funcA, funcB,....". Here it shows "..libname.obj" which is different. Secondly, I've pointed the library directory, and the library name already. it is all, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know. Turn on the linker debug output and verify.

Comment: how silly! my library name lacks of ".lib". But now it comes with the LNK2005 (unresolved external symbol) and it says "Error 15 fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib' test_filesystem test_filesystem" -> do I put the library name correctly? -> libboost_filesystem-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib? I normally put library name like this

Comment: boost links itself in strange ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I've now solved the problem. Partly, it is from the hint "boost links itself"

I installed boost 1.5.3 which includes all "libxx-vc100-xx-1_53.lib" and these libs are intended to use for VS2010 (vc10) compiler.

I didn't notice this and compiled my example in VS2008 (vc9) and boost/compiler something links automatically to vc9 libraries which are not available.

=> I solved it by compiling the same project in VS2010 and finally DONE